# Error handling Async Waterfall with nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

I am using async.parallel inside `async.waterfall( [] , function() )`. The code is as follows:

```
async.waterfall(
  [
    function first(callback) {
      //some processing
      callback();
    },
    function second(result, callback) {
      //Here i query the db
      model.findAll()
        .then(function(success) {
          async.parallel(
            [array_of_functions],
            function done(err, result) {
              if (err) {
                callback(err);
              }
            }
          )
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          callback(err);
        })
    }
  ],
  function done(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
)
```

Sometime i gets an error on console:

> callback was already called

The error message tells that callback is getting invoked multiple times. I think `callback(err)` inside `async.parallel()` and `.catch()` are getting invoked simultaneously. 
This essentially means that if an error occurs **INSIDE** `.then()` it gets caught in `.catch()`. Is this how it works? Secondly if I wish to propagate error in nested callback to final `done()` function of `async.waterfall()` how can I do that.

Comment: "simultaneously" - It is not possible in Node.js, as it has only one thread.

Comment: Oh i mean to say one after the other. When i test this function, the server never send back response and console shows the message i have mentioned in question

Comment: Do you have any code after `if (err) {...}`?

Comment: Yes there is code after `if (err) {...}` in `async.parallel()`

Comment: It seems to be name conflict. Maybe you have `callback` in `[array_of_functions]`. And your questions. First if an error occurs in `then` it dosn't caught in `catch`. Second you can call inner callbacks with error to reach in inner asyc handler e.g `done` in paralllel or call `waterfall` callback with error

Comment: @SohaibFarooqi Hmmm, then the only thing I could think of is that, you are not returning after `callback(err)`, so the rest of the code is executed which again calls `callback`.

Comment: @thefourtheye so i should do it like `return callback(err)` instead of just `callback(err)`?

Comment: Yes. Normally, there is no reason to continue after handling an error scenario.

Comment: oh right.! I will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I guess it's a name conflict as Ebrahim mentioned. Try to simply rename your callbacks. e.g. name the callback in `second` function simply `secondCallback` like so `function second(result, secondCallback)...` and in model.findAll().then async.paralel function use paralelCallback for example.

Comment: The names in actual code are different. The code i have posted here is just pseudo-code for understanding purpose